# Add AWS Lambda function trigger to existing function using Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, boto3

Currently I have a lambda function that is created in a different Terrraform module.  I need to create a Cloudwatch Logs trigger for that lambda function from a serperate repository.  So far, I don't see any Terraform resources (that I know of) to do this.  I have also looked into using Boto3 in local-exec through terraform.  This doesn't look possible either. Are there any ways that I am missing, that can complete this using Terraform, AWS_CLI, or python.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a `aws_cloudwatch_log_subscription_filter` with the Lambda function's ARN as the destination value. You could pass the Lambda function's ARN into the CloudWatch module, or you could have it [lookup the function by name](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/lambda_function) to get the ARN. You'll probably also need to create an `aws_lambda_permission` resource to give CloudWatch permission to invoke the Lambda function.

Comment: How would I connect that to the specific logs in Cloudwatch from that Lambda function?  I have one lambda function that needs the trigger from the cloudwatch logs so that it can forward those logs.  The cloudwatch logs are ones from a seperate lambda function execution.

Comment: I just updated my answer, I had a typo in there with the wrong terraform resource name. The `aws_cloudwatch_log_subscription_filter` is the thing that creates a trigger to stream CloudWatch logs to a Lambda function. That resource is where you specify the log group, and the Lambda function the logs should stream to.

Comment: This ended up working.  Thanks for the help!